# Laravel: Accessing an Array within an Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to access an Array, which is saved inside another array.

I have an Author Model which looks like this:

```
public function chapters() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Chapter', 'Book');
}
```

Then I want to go ahead and grab all chapters, that are written by an author:

```
$chapters = Author::with('chapters')->where('id', $author->id()->get());
```

But when I want to return the chapters, they are saved within an array.

```
return dd($chapters->toArray());
```

Which looks like this:

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
  array (size=15)
    'id' => int 4
    'email' => string 'user@email.com' (length=18)
    'chapters' => 
      array (size=7)
        0 => 
          array (size=15)
            ...
        1 => 
          array (size=15)
            ...
        2 => 
          array (size=15)
            ...
        3 => 
          array (size=15)
            ...
        4 => 
          array (size=15)
            ...
        5 => 
          array (size=15)
            ...
        6 => 
          array (size=15)
            ...
```

But I want my array to look actually something like this:

```
array (size=4)
0 => 
  array (size=15)
    'id' => int 504
    'rating1' => int 48
    'rating2' => int 51
1 => 
  array (size=15)
    'id' => int 505
    'rating1' => int 96
    'rating2' => int 96

2 => 
  array (size=15)
    'id' => int 506
    'rating1' => int 7
    'rating2' => int 5
3 => 
  array (size=15)
    'id' => int 507
    'rating1' => int 21
    'rating2' => int 21
```

So that I could actually do this:

```
 return dd($chapters->lists('rating1'));
```

How can I currently get an accessible array of the chapters?

Thanks and kind regards, george

Comment: Not an array but a Collection, and simply do this instead of `Author::with...` -> `$author->chapters->lists('rating1');`

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I did this: 


$author = User::with('chapters')->where('id', $user->id)->get();
  
$author = $author->chapters->lists('rating1');

And I get an Error Exception:

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$scores

Comment: `get` returns a collection, while you want `first` or `find` to fetch single model. So `User::with('chapters')->find($id);`

Comment: Thank you, you're awesome. Could you write your comment as an answer, so that I could give it a 'solution' tag. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
$author = User::with('chapters')->find($id);

$chapters = $author->chapters;

// then:
$chapters->lists('rating1');
```